# Dependencies issue in manually installing module with activeperl

Tags: perl, xampp, activeperl

ok here is the complete story, i got referenced into this site :
https://github.com/Kimtaro/jisho.org ,
The source is great, i just want to test to get it runs offline in my local server with XAMPP 
Where my details are as follows : 
Windows 7 32 bit ultimate, XAMPP v1.7.2 , ActivePerl 5.16.3 Build 1603

i got the compressed files and tried to install it manually with
           perl makefile.pl

then here comes the problem :
Can't locate inc/Module/Install.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl/site/lib C:/Perl/lib .) at makefile.pl line 1. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at makefile.pl line 1.

I haven't tried the strawberry Perl , but my question is , "Is this the dependecy problem ?" since i tried to look and i haven't found that install.pm in the perl directory.
i've been struggling to find the solution anywhere, even if there's a tiny bit of clue to solve it, i'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

"Is this the dependecy problem"

Yes, usually.

If you had deployed this module from a built version, that you found on CPAN, `inc::Module::Install` would have been bundled with that module in its `inc/` directory.

However, because you're using the source checkout, you need to have the pre-requisites locally.

Recommending course of action: [Install `cpanm`](https://metacpan.org/pod/App%3a%3acpanminus#Installing-to-system-perl), and then install `Module::Install`

Installing `cpanm` is the hard part, not sure how you do that on Win32.

However, once you have, installing Module::Install is easy:

```
cpanm Module::Install
```

On active Perl, you could probably use `CPAN.pm` that comes with it, but I'm out of touch how that works and `cpanm` is a valuable investment.

But basically, yes, you have a dependency problem.

And you need to solve that somehow to proceed.

However, exactly how to solve that depends on your system.